# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/abs__ic_search')

Tags: android

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/action_label_search"/>
```

I have error in line 2.(@drawable/abs__ic_search)

Comment: do you have the drawable `abs_ic_search` in the drawable folder?

Comment: Does your drawable folder contains abs__ic_search image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in my app. I used actionbarsherlock and forgot to import.

Answer (score 1):

```
Add one picture in drawable folder with name abs_ic_search.it will resolve.
```

Answer (score 1):

add image with name abs__ic_search in drawable folder or use default search icon

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don'n have the resource named **abs__ic_search** in your drawable folder. Simply place it there and clean the workspace and run the app again. Change name to abs_ic_search also.